# Windows to go failing to boot when changing usb-C to usb-A

Tags: windows, boot, usb, windows-to-go

I've got an external SSD which works just fine with usb-C connection and Windows-to-go installed on it.

Unfortunately if I plug it in using the usb-C-to-usb-A converter included with it, my UEFI boot just refuses to use it. I don't get any messages beyond the "failed to boot" at BIOS level.

How do I even begin to debug this? And what could be the reason this happens?

The hardware is a Dell XPS 15 7590.

Comment: The most likely reason it's not working is because it has no driver for the adapter to load, therefore it won't recognize any device connected to it.  It might help to know the model of your PC too.

Comment: @pigeonburger good point, I added the laptop model to the question.

Comment: In the Dell BIOS menu, try setting fastboot to "thorough" and then see if it recognizes your device then

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be with how the EFI entry was defined. The entry I was starting was too specific and included the pci bus and usb port where the disk was expected.

Changing the entry using `efibootmgr` to use only the GPT device identifier worked just fine.